# Ubuntu 18.04 suddenly does not detect a monitor

Tags: 18.04, external-monitor

I have a laptop where I have dual boot of Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10, and one external monitor. Windows 10 detects the monitor without any problems. But Ubuntu suddenly became unable to detect the monitor although it could detect the monitor and display without any problems. Please help me.

Comment: What do your logs say about the issue? Start with /var/log/syslog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, my Ubuntu 18.04 is able to detect the external display. But I do not know which package was needed to be up to date.